# Getting Chopin Ballade No. 1 up to tempo+keeping hands together

Tags: piano, practice, tempo, chopin

I am trying to learn Ballade No. 1 op. 23 by Chopin(2 as well, but that's not important to this) I have been playing for about 7 years, and I have been without a teacher for several years. My biggest problem is getting the tempo correct and keeping my hands in time. The slow parts are too fast, and the fast parts are too slow. whenever I try to pick up the pace, I make huge mistakes and/or cannot get my hands to synchronize. I am especially having trouble with(in this recording

) 4:03-4:32, 6:59-7:53, and the Coda. How do you get your hands to play in time with each other in the faster sections, while keeping musical integrity?

Comment: Sorry, but I believe that your question is too opinion-based (and, as such, off topic here). Providing such high level suggestion requires a "hands-on" reference from anybody trying to provide those suggestions (aka: a teacher): even if we suggest you something, it might not suit your hands, experience, current technique and awareness of musicianship. About the last point, who says that you're playing it "too slow"? That's just an assumption. There are plenty of *important* recordings that some consider played at the "wrong" tempo. Music timing is not absolute, but it has to be *consistent*.

Comment: The question is too broad to be answerable. There are many different techniques and musical problems in any one of the sections mentioned, and there's no one answer to cover them all (other than "practice more", "practice slowly more", "stay relaxed", "use a metronome", etc.). I recommend narrowing the problems down to the specific measures involved and posting a separate question for each problem. If possible, videos of you playing each problem area would be helpful, too, so we can see your hands.

Comment: @Aaron and even with those videos, that could be still very much open to any opinion.